# I'm using an external DNS, can my ISP detect that?

Tags: dns, isp, privacy-protection

I tend to use Google's public DNS, I don't like my ISP DNS because it takes too much time to refresh.

Today I have got a page from them saying that you should change the DNS to their DNS because they are doing some fixing?

Are they really able to do so and am I really safe if I use their DNS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ISP still has the ability to see where you route your traffic, regardless of it is to their DNS or to another open DNS provider like GOOGLE DNS or OPENDNS.

In either case, it is best to either a) set your DNS Settings directly on the router, or b) directly on any pc that doesn't wish to use your ISP's DNS.

Not really a matter of safety here; they are your ISP, they can see what you are routing; unless you decide to use an external proxy that routes your traffic only to that proxy and then out to other sites, the ISP can see pretty much anything you do on your network connection.

Note, they are NOT able to force you to use their DNS; that is your decision, and something you can directly override, but they can provide page redirection, etc, and inform you of DNS outages, changes, and such.

Comment: and ads. my isp redirects to ads, which is why i set the dns on my router manually.

Comment: The ISP usually is not permitted to redirect any traffic to external advertising; as popups etc are tightly controlled.  I would check your computer for malware using MalwareBytes Antimalware or Dr. Web Cureit to see if you have any infections that are adware.

Comment: it redirects to a captive page which also has ads

Comment: If your ISP requires authentication, or you are using a public ISP, or a free wifi ISP, it could very well redirect you to a captive portal.  Meaning, you must sign up for the service prior to gaining access to the ISP's network.  However, if it is a normal ISP, and you already pay them for access, and it is redirecting to a captive page it is most likely spwyare, or adware causing your issue.  You could also CALL them to ensure that there is nothing else going on.  Who is your provider?

Comment: Almost all ISPs that I am aware of reroute faulty DNS lookups to their own page. They usually suggest what they *think* you were trying to find along with a bunch of context appropriate ads.

Comment: The browser, the ISP, the DNS provider all have the ability to capture faulty DNS.  Wanted to clarify that.  It all depends on what the OP is using, and what the situations around the request are.

Comment: http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow_viewer/0,3253,l%253D287034%2526a%253D246609%2526po%253D4,00.asp?p=n

Comment: I assume you mean this is what it is doing; Verizon, OpenDNS, and several other providers, and even some browser, will detect faulty requests, like bad URL's, or sites they cannot find, and offer suggestions, as @EBGreen up there stated.  This is not abnormal, and really isn't that big of a privacy concern.

Comment: @zackrspv Technically, they *can force* you to use their DNS... as they *can* restrict any/all traffic to/from you to the public internet.  As far as legality goes... it's dependent on the country/contract you are in/have signed etc...  Now, weather or not they *will* restrict you is another matter entirely.

Comment: @TheCompWiz, true, my answer was more subjective to the USA; not a very good tactic to use here, and in all my years in the computer world (just about 2 decades [god i feel old saying that]) i have yet to come across one who FORCES the user to use one.  But yes, given a different country, bypassing an ISP's DNS could be seen as a suspicious act, thus could be forced to use theirs.  However, i think the OP was more referring to what his Verizon ISP was doing.

Comment: @zackrspv  I feel your pain... and can 100% relate.  [You Must have started on the internet around the same time as me.]  But USA-based ISPs do in-fact limit traffic quite regularly... for a variety of reasons.  (everything from "optimizing networks" (read screwing customers by caching results or making their own services look better than competitors...) to keepin' their customers from known bad-sites.  There is no telling what Verizon is up to.  They're on my official "poo" list for ISPs.

Comment: @TheCompWiz, My first pc was an 8086 lol.  So, dang, man now i sound much older lol.  Indeed, Verizon is on my own crap list too, i still use them for cell phone access, but ISP, no no no lol.

Comment: 8086?   I had my old 8080 laying around up until a few years ago... you started late in the game :D